# Log Scripts running on Jenkins Script Console

Tags: security, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I'd like to write all scripts run in jenkins' script console to the log file so I can monitor what is being run. Currently if I type a simple script in the web console nothing is written out to the /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log file. I'd also like to see who is executing those commands as well (ie which user). I've tried to change the log configuration, but there isn't any clear information out there that I could use to do this.

Audit Plugin - No Success
Log Recorder - org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity - No Success